# Dissmissed UIViewController didreceivememorywarning - swift

Tags: ios, swift, didreceivememorywarning

I have a custom `UIImagePickerController` that still, after being dismissed and the variable set to nil is receiving memory warnings, and it is causing my app to crash because of it.

Here is my `UIImagePickerController`

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class Picker: UIImagePickerController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var myView = PickerView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var takenImages = [UIImage]()
var takenImagesThumbs = [UIImage]()
override init() {
    super.init()
    myView.picker = self
    self.delegate = self
    self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    self.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
    self.showsCameraControls = false
    self.cameraOverlayView = myView
    self.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Photo
    self.setFullscreen()
    myView.viewing()
}
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
func setFullscreen(){
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let scale = screenSize.height / screenSize.width*3/4
    let translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,(screenSize.height - screenSize.width*4/3)*0.5);
    let fullScreen = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
    self.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(fullScreen, translate)
}
var endFunc:((images:[UIImage], thumbs:[UIImage]) -> Void)!
var ViewController:UIViewController!
func show(vc:UIViewController, complete: ((images:[UIImage], thumbs:[UIImage]) -> Void)) {
    vc.presentViewController(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
    endFunc = complete
    ViewController = vc
}
var closeQueue = dispatch_queue_create("areyouareyou", nil)
func close() {
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        dispatch_async(self.closeQueue) {
            self.endFunc(images: self.takenImages, thumbs: self.takenImagesThumbs)
            self.takenImagesThumbs = [UIImage]()
            self.takenImages = [UIImage]()
            self.myView.update(self.takenImages.count)
        }
    }
    self.removeFromParentViewController()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}
var resizequeue = dispatch_queue_create("hangingthree", nil)
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    myView.takeButton.enabled = true
    let nfo = info as NSDictionary
    var image:UIImage = nfo.valueForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as UIImage
    takenImages.append(image)
    self.myView.update(self.takenImages.count)
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        dispatch_async(self.resizequeue) {
            var theimg = Common.resizeImage(image, scaledToSize: CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 3, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 3))
            self.takenImagesThumbs.append(theimg)
        }
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    println(self.takenImages.count)
}
}
```

and here is my overlayview

```
import UIKit

class PickerView: UIView {
var picker:Picker!

var takeButton = UIButton()
var takeButtonPath = UIBezierPath()
var takeButtonLayer = CAShapeLayer()
var takeButtonIconLayer = CAShapeLayer()

var closeButton = UIButton()
var closeButtonBgPath = UIBezierPath()
var closeButtonBgLayer = CAShapeLayer()

var bottomBar:UIVisualEffectView!
var imageCount = UILabel()
override init() {
    super.init()
}
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
func viewing() {
    var colors = Colors()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    imageCount.frame = CGRectMake(62, 0, 30, 31)
    imageCount.text = "0"
    imageCount.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    imageCount.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 20)
}
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    var colors = Colors()
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, colors.pickerStrokeColor.CGColor)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, colors.pickerFillColor.CGColor)

    var point = CGPointMake((self.bounds.width / 2), self.bounds.height - 30)
    var start = CGFloat(Common.radians(0))
    var end = CGFloat(Common.radians(360))

    var moon = UIBezierPath()
    moon.addArcWithCenter(point, radius: 45, startAngle: end, endAngle: start, clockwise: true)
    moon.stroke()
    moon.fill()

    var left = UIBezierPath()
    left.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, point.y))
    left.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(point.x - 45, point.y))
    left.stroke()

    var right = UIBezierPath()
    right.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(self.bounds.width, point.y))
    right.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(point.x + 45, point.y))
    right.stroke()

    btnCloseing()
    btnTakeing()
    bottomBaring()
    //add
    self.addSubview(closeButton)
    self.addSubview(takeButton)
}
func bottomBaring() {
    var point = CGPointMake((self.bounds.width / 2), self.bounds.height - 30)
    var frame = CGRectMake(0, point.y, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height - point.y)
    //blur
    var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    bottomBar = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    bottomBar.frame = frame 
    //blur add
    self.addSubview(bottomBar)
    //vib
    var vibEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect)
    var vibView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibEffect)
    vibView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.width, frame.height)
    //add
    vibView.contentView.addSubview(imageCount)
    bottomBar.contentView.addSubview(vibView)
}
func btnCloseing() {
    var start = CGFloat(Common.radians(0))
    var end = CGFloat(Common.radians(360))
    var colors = Colors()
    closeButtonBgPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(0, 0), radius: 20, startAngle: start, endAngle: end, clockwise: true)
    closeButtonBgLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(-40, -40, 40, 40)
    closeButtonBgLayer.path = closeButtonBgPath.CGPath
    closeButtonBgLayer.fillColor = colors.pickerCloseBtnFill.CGColor
    closeButtonBgLayer.strokeColor = colors.pickerStrokeColor.CGColor
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.width - 50, 10, 40, 40)
    closeButton.layer.addSublayer(closeButtonBgLayer)
    closeButton.setTitle("X", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    closeButton.setTitleColor(colors.pickerStrokeColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    closeButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 25)
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "closePhoto", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
}
func btnTakeing() {
    var start = CGFloat(Common.radians(0))
    var end = CGFloat(Common.radians(360))
    var point = CGPointMake((self.bounds.width / 2), self.bounds.height - 30)
    takeButtonPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(0, 0), radius: 40, startAngle: start, endAngle: end, clockwise: true)
    takeButtonLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(-80, -90, 80, 80)
    takeButtonLayer.path = takeButtonPath.CGPath
    takeButtonLayer.fillColor = Colors().pickerTakeBtnFill.CGColor
    takeButtonLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    takeButtonIconLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "CameraIcon")?.CGImage
    takeButtonIconLayer.frame = CGRectMake(26, 30, 30, 30)
    takeButton.frame = CGRectMake(point.x - 40, point.y - 50, 80, 100)
    takeButton.layer.addSublayer(takeButtonLayer)
    takeButton.layer.addSublayer(takeButtonIconLayer)
    takeButton.addTarget(self, action: "takePhoto", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
    takeButton.addTarget(self, action: "takePhotoEnd", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    takeButton.addTarget(self, action: "takePhotoEnd", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpOutside)
}
func takePhoto() {
    self.takeButton.enabled = false
    takeButtonLayer.fillColor = Colors().pickerTakeBtnFillClick.CGColor
    picker.takePicture()
}
func takePhotoEnd() {
    takeButtonLayer.fillColor = Colors().pickerTakeBtnFill.CGColor
}
func closePhoto() {
    picker.close()
}
func update(count: Int) {
    imageCount.text = String(count)
}
}
```

Anyone knows the problem or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are subclassing `UIImagePickerController` which is prohibited. Read the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html):

> IMPORTANT
>
> The `UIImagePickerController` class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and **does not support subclassing**. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the `cameraOverlayView` property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.